# Receiving error Timestamp '5/9/2022 11:09' is not recognized

Tags: sql, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Gives this error when trying to convert this date format in snowflake.

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('5/9/2022 11:09')

Timestamp '5/9/2022 11:09' is not recognized

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to use two digits for date and month

Comment: Desired output is '2022-05-0911:09:00.000' when I only run SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('5/9/2022') it does work. This is for a large data set unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a format string:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('5/9/2022 11:09', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI');

-- Or if US based date format:
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('5/9/2022 11:09', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI');
```

This is required because 5/9/2022 is ambiguous. In Europe it's September 5. In the US it's May 9.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an arbitrary timestamp format hoping the DBMS will guess what it means. I must admit I can't. Is this May 9 or September 5?

You may be lucky that the DBMS accepts this format and even guesses right. But instead if relying on luck, you should give the DBMS the information it needs, i.e. the format. Or better still use a timestamp literal right away:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-05-09 11:09:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please execute the query including seconds like below

SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('5/9/2022 11:09:00');

Answer (score 0):

Previous MySQL versions allowed for the use of a "relaxed" date expression. This means that you could use **any** delimiters at all for the date parts, e.g. `2004@04@16`, `2022=09=17`, `1968.04.22`, were all considered to be valid.

But as of MySQL 8.0.29, this is no longer allowed. You now have to use a `-` (hyphen) as the delimiter.

You can read the [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-deprecations) for more information

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1, TO_TIMESTAMP(column1, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi') as ts
FROM VALUES
  ('5/9/2022 11:09'),
  ('5/12/2022 12:09'),
  ('5/24/2022 23:09');
```

| COLUMN1 | TS |
| --- | --- |
| 5/9/2022 11:09 | 2022-05-09 11:09:00.000 |
| 5/12/2022 12:09 | 2022-05-12 12:09:00.000 |
| 5/24/2022 23:09 | 2022-05-24 23:09:00.000 |

so you "this is for a large data set" does not make sense..

do you mean you data set has mixed formatted data?

at which point the TRY_ functions can be used, to try things in rank order:

```
SELECT 
    column1 
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(column1, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi') as ts_a
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(column1, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as ts_b
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(column1, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss.ff6') as ts_c
    ,coalesce(ts_a, ts_b, ts_c) as ts
FROM VALUES
('5/9/2022 11:09'),
('5/12/2022'),
('5/24/2022 23:09'),
('5/24/2022 23:09:59.99999');
```

| COLUMN1 | TS_A | TS_B | TS_C | TS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/9/2022 11:09 | 2022-05-09 11:09:00.000 | null | null | 2022-05-09 11:09:00.000 |
| 5/12/2022 | null | 2022-05-12 00:00:00.000 | null | 2022-05-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 5/24/2022 23:09 | 2022-05-24 23:09:00.000 | null | null | 2022-05-24 23:09:00.000 |
| 5/24/2022 23:09:59.99999 | null | null | 2022-05-24 23:09:59.999 | 2022-05-24 23:09:59.999 |

and that can be merge into a single command to clean that up:

```
SELECT 
    column1 
    ,coalesce(TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(column1, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi'), TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(column1, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(column1, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss.ff6')) as ts
FROM VALUES
('5/9/2022 11:09'),
('5/12/2022'),
('5/24/2022 23:09'),
('5/24/2022 23:09:59.99999');
```

| COLUMN1 | TS |
| --- | --- |
| 5/9/2022 11:09 | 2022-05-09 11:09:00.000 |
| 5/12/2022 | 2022-05-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 5/24/2022 23:09 | 2022-05-24 23:09:00.000 |
| 5/24/2022 23:09:59.99999 | 2022-05-24 23:09:59.999 |